# SP2013: Disable Column in GridView

Tags: 2013, jquery, gridview

I have a list which is shown in gridview **(Quick Edit** in the ribbon). Now i want to disable one **column** with **jQuery**.

This might be possible by applying the attribute

```
aria-readonly="true"
```

to the correct  element.

For example a disabled column looks like this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; border-right: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); 
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); color: rgb(177, 177, 177); 
font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;,&quot;Segoe&quot;,Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; text-align: start; 
background-color: rgb(253, 253, 253);" class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2" role="gridcell" 
aria-selected="true" aria-readonly="true" id="spgridcontainer_WPQ2_0_3_8" 
aria-describedby="spgridcontainer_WPQ2_0_8"><span>Germany</span></td>
```

A normal (editable) column looks like this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle; border-right: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); 
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(198, 198, 198); color: rgb(68, 68, 68); 
font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;,&quot;Segoe&quot;,Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
font-size: 13px; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-align: left;" 
class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2" role="gridcell" 
aria-selected="false"><span>Not Started</span></td>
```

Can somebody jump onboard and help me with the correct jQuery commands to select the column and apply the attributes?

Comment: how can You solved the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the most dynamic solution but it should work... replace col_index with the column number... could add more before the "td" selector, such as the container id or class name to make the selection more fine-tuned.

```
$('tr>td[role="gridcell"]:nth-child(col_index)').attr("aria-readonly","true");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same goal with my custom field. The best way to do it is to apply the View template for your column with jslink. In the view template you can check if the field is rendered in Quick Edit (`inGridMode`) and set `AllowGridEditing` to false on the field:

```
if (ctx.inGridMode) {
    field.AllowGridEditing = false;
}
```

Suppose you have a field called `Request_x0020_Status`. Here is a complete example:

```
(function () {
    var view = function (ctx, field) {
        if (ctx.inGridMode) {
            field.AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
        return window.RenderFieldValueDefault(ctx);
    };
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.Fields = {
        'Request_x0020_Status': {
            'View': view
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

More details about how to set it up can be found on my blog post:

- [chuvash.eu: Disabling a column in Quick Edit](http://chuvash.eu/2014/11/28/disabling-a-column-in-quick-edit/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code can edit setting.

`ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].AllowGridEditing = false;`

Answer (score -1):

Expression might be ok but aria-readonly does not disable a field in quick edit view.

Comment: Hi Rob! Can you please try to add more details to your post?  Right now it is not very helpful :)